# How do i get x, y coordinate values when click on map?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-server

I am very preliminary in arc gis and in fact i am a web programmer.

I created a local serviece and use this to create a web applcation in ArcGIS > ArcGIS Server for the Microsoft .NET Framework > ArcGIS Server Manager.exe .

Then i copy website from "c:/inetpup/wwwroot/projectName" and open this to VisualStudio.

Now i want when i click on map, display an pushpin on click location and send x, y to server.